# AMQ6709 for Linear logs

Tags: ibm-mq

I am getting the following error message in the MQ error logs:

AMQ6709: The log for queue manager is full

I checked the qm.ini file of the qmgr and this is the output:

```
Log:
LogPrimaryFiles=5
LogSecondaryFiles=2
LogFilePages=4096
LogType=LINEAR
LogBufferPages=512
LogPath=/var/mqm/log/EMQ02OD1/
LogWriteIntegrity=TripleWrite
Service:
Name=AuthorizationService
EntryPoints=10
ServiceComponent:
Service=AuthorizationService
Name=MQSeries.UNIX.auth.service
Module=amqzfu
ComponentDataSize=0
Channels:
AdoptNewMCA=ALL
MaxChannels=300
MaxActiveChannels=280
TCP:
Keepalive=YES
```

How can i clean the logs, LINEAR LOGS, so the log records can be written again in the AMQERR01.LOG??

Comment: What version of IBM MQ is this queue manager?  Can you provide the full error from the AMQERR01.LOG? Is this a new queue manager?  How old is the oldest S*.LOG file?

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.con.doc/q018950_.htm